# Embeded Jetty, kill Request after a given time

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I run a jar with an embedded Jetty. From time to time it happens that one request get stuck in some endless loop. Obviously fixing the endless-loop would be the best option. However, this is currently not possible.

So I am looking for an option, that checks if a request exists for more than e.g. 5 minutes, and kills the corresponding thread.

I tried the typical Jetty options:

- maxIdleTime
- soLingerTime
- stopTimeout

None of them worked as expected. Is there another option to consider?

Answer (score 1):

Do you access to the code that kicks of the code which takes too long to complete? If so you can use callable and an Executor to achieve this yourself, below is a unit test with an example:

```
@Test
public void timerTest() throws Exception
{
  //create an executor
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

  //some code to run
  Callable callable = () -> {
    Thread.sleep(10000); //sleep for 10 seconds
    return 123;
  };

  //run the callable code
  Future<Integer> future = (Future<Integer>) executor.submit(callable);

  Integer value = future.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); //this will timeout after 5 seconds

  //kill the thread
  future.cancel(true);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using Future is a good idea. I was hoping for a jetty-side solution. Since jetty does the thread handling as well.